# How to remove delta search from firefox new tab

Tags: firefox

When I click on new tab on Firefox delta search loads.I have tried by all means to remove it but am unable to remove it.

Answer (score 5):

Its a little extreme, but I just tend to reset firefox and reinstall my extensions. This will not affect bookmarks, cookies or anything important, and will create a set of backups in any case on your desktop. I do this semi regularly for a less computer savvy family member who seems to get various search engine hijacks every so often, and it always works

[image]

go to troubleshooting information

[image]

Reset firefox to its default state.

Reinstall any extensions you actually need again

Comment: A thorough scan with a good updated AV and something like MBAM is also recommended.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. I have both on my dad's laptop. I have to deal with this sorta the every month or so, and *just* setting the default search either does nothing, or breaks something else. I kinda take the AV and MBAM for granted.

Comment: The advice was obviously meant for the OP and not a geek like you. :) I sympathise with you though - this is something all of us who do free tech support for clueless relatives and friends have to face quite often.

Comment: Well, for now, it pays for school, technically and i can't learn as much if things don't break ;p. I'm more mad at whoever thinks its perfectly fine to hijack someone's search engine, and install a whole load of unwanted garbage. They need to find honest work, like loansharking, and mugging babies for lollypops.

Comment: Ha, although I'm sure you'd find babies being mugged galore if it was as profitable. :/

Answer (score 2):

It probably changed Firefox's preferences, so you will have to reset them manually.

There's a removal process documented here:

http://deletemalware.blogspot.com/2013/02/remove-delta-searchcom-redirect-delta.html

And one more thing, make sure you removed the culprit; otherwise, I'm afraid the Delta Search nuisance may return. If you don't know where it came from, use AdwCleaner.

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/

P.S. it's actually amazing how this "search engine" made its way to top 100 sites in just a few months. I suspect black magic :)

Comment: Your first link seems the slightest bit dubious - specifically the tool that's been recommended. ALL the malware removal 'tools' are the same one, and it seems to be using what seems to be a dodgy referral/affliate site.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "about:config". Search "Delta". Right-click each entries and click "Reset". See detail from here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/957776

Answer (score 1):

Type in the address line `about:config` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Confirm the message. Look for *Delta*. Right-click the entries and click *Reset*. Please be aware to reset only the entries that contains *browser.newtab* or *browser.search*.

Answer (score 0):

Type in about:config in address bar and hit "Enter",then in the search menu type "browser.newtab.url" and press "Enter"Right click on the entry and click "modify" from the options.Now you can specify your preferred address or leave it blank.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to remove Delta Search from Firefox new tab:

1. Enter `about:config` in Firefox address bar
2. Search `browser.newtab.url`
3. Right-click then click "reset"

Now you'll see value as about:newtab...

That's it; you have successfully removed the annoying Delta Search engine page when you are opening a new tab.